# RF24 if statements are not reading properly, even if an "if" value is wrong, it still follows the associated code

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, nrf24l01+

My code is taking values from a remote and transmitting the state of it. Right now the states are just 1 and 0, on or off, and is writing over the serial monitor on the transmitting Arduino. On the receiving RF module I can't seem to get my if statements working right

Transmitter code:

```
const char a[] = "1";
const char b[] = "0";
void loop() {
if (Serial.available ( ) > 0) 
{
char state = Serial.read(); // reading the value from the remote

if (state >= 0)
{
digitalWrite (7, HIGH); //turning LED on transmitting breadboard on to compare to recieving breadboard
radio.write(&a, sizeof(a)); //tell the other arduino that the value is 1
}
if (state < 0)
{
digitalWrite(7,LOW);
radio.write(&b,sizeof(b)); //tell other arduino value is 0
}
}
```

reciever code:

```
void loop()
{
if (radio.available())
{
char state[32] = {0};

radio.read(&state, sizeof(state));
Serial.println(state);
int a = state;
if (a = 1);
{
  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
  Serial.println("do something");
}
if (a = 0);
{
digitalWrite(7,LOW);
Serial.println("do nothing");
}
}
```

receiving serial monitor

```
1
do something
do nothing
0
do something
do nothing
0
do something
do nothing
```

and my light stays off on the receiving Arduino, why does it print both statements? A is 1, but it prints the value that's supposed to be printed when a is 0 also, i'm so confused

Comment: print `sizeof(state)` also ... is it what you expect?

Comment: `if (a = 1); {`  ... `if (a = 0); {`   You've got what amounts to four typos there.  At minimum two of them will be pointed out to you if you turn up the warning level in the IDE preferences.

Comment: Start with some simple code which is known to work such as: https://forum.arduino.cc/t/simple-nrf24l01-2-4ghz-transceiver-demo/405123/2. `Serial.read()` returns a negative value (-1)  if no data is available but you already check that data is available before issuing the command. The code you have published is anyway badly formatted and incomplete.

Comment: @timemage Could you please make an answer? A comment is for clarifying the question.

Comment: @6v6gt Your comment is not requesting more information about the question.

Comment: @NickGammon In short: no.  You're demonstrating that you don't understand the purpose of my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (a = 1);
{
  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
  Serial.println("do something");
}
```

Two major problems here. In C++ you test for equality for `==`, not `=`.

Second, putting the semicolon after the `if` terminates the scope of the `if`.

That should read:

```
if (a == 1)
{
  digitalWrite(7,HIGH);
  Serial.println("do something");
}
```

---

```
char state[32] = {0};

radio.read(&state, sizeof(state));
Serial.println(state);
int a = state;
```

`state` is an array. If you assign that to `a` you will get the same array, in another variable. That array will not be zero or one.

Maybe you mean:

```
int a = state [0];
```